# What is wrong with my SQL in SelectLayerByAttribute?

Tags: where-clause, arcpy

My code is `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("polygons_file", "NEW_SELECTION", "Shape_Area=(SELECT MAX(Shape_Area) FROM polygons_file")`

I am getting an error "The SQL expression is invalid."

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries should work, but you have a mismatched parentheses.

Wrong: `Shape_Area=(SELECT MAX(Shape_Area) FROM polygons_file`
Right: `Shape_Area=(SELECT MAX(Shape_Area) FROM polygons_file)`

Also note the [different field delimiters to use depending on your data source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000) (e.g. shapefile or geodatabase); you *may* need to include quotation marks around `Shape_Area`, e.g.

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('polygons_file', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"Shape_Area" = (SELECT MAX("Shape_Area") FROM polygons_file)')`

Comment: Thank you Erica for your answer.I have tried your code but argis has gave error again .I checked my code there isn't problem paretheses or  quotation marks.I want to select the largest area.Can i writing differently from that.